# MapServer 7 and File Geodatabases and Expressions

Tags: wfs, mapserver, file-geodatabase

I am trying to define within my map definition document test1.map a layer that comes from a ESRI file geodatabase (from ArcMap 10.2), and display different styles/fill colors for each item based upon a field within the layer, in this case ws_condition.  I have defined it like this:

```
LAYER
    NAME "analysis_sp__test1__a1__demo2__ws_condition"
    TYPE POLYGON
    STATUS ON
    PROJECTION 
        "init=epsg:32049"
    END 
    METADATA 
        "wms_title" "ws_conditionLayer"
        "wfs_title" "ws_conditionLayer"
        "wfs_srs"    "EPSG:32049"
        "gml_include_items" "all"
        "gml_featureid"  "objectid"
        "wfs_enable_request" "*"
    END
    CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
    CONNECTION "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\demo1\data\demo1.gdb"
    DATA "demo2__a1__test1__merged"             
    CLASS
        EXPRESSION('[ws_condition]' < -.6)
        STYLE
            COLOR 255 0 0 
            OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
        END         

    END
    CLASS
        EXPRESSION('[ws_condition]' > -.6 AND '[ws_condition]' < -.2)
        STYLE
            COLOR 240 128 128
            OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
        END         

    END
    CLASS
        EXPRESSION('[ws_condition]' > -.2 AND '[ws_condition]' < .2)
        STYLE
            COLOR 229 204 255
            OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
        END         

    END
    CLASS
        EXPRESSION('[ws_condition]' > .2 AND '[ws_condition]' < .6) 
        STYLE
            COLOR 142 229 238
            OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
        END         

    END
    CLASS
        EXPRESSION('[ws_condition]' > .6)
        STYLE
            COLOR 0 0 139
            OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
        END         

    END

END
```

Now I receive nothing on the map, and worse, when I try to open it inside of the MapServer Manager, I receive an error saying there is a parsing error.   Is there any way to make this work within the map definition file, or possibly how to create a simple WFS server layer in OpenLayers (keeping it simple, the WFS server will be on the same server and domain as the OpenLayers server).   I have tried many different things, including trying to use CLASSITEM and specifying the field name, but it seems to only be doing a string comparison and not a numeric comparison.

Comment: Are you running on Windows  32bit or 64bit

Answer (score 1):

It's doing a string comparison because you are saying in your expression you have a string when using the quote.

For a numeric comparison you need expressions like:

```
EXPRESSION([ws_condition] > .6)
```